# jEditable: pass TinyMCE content back to textarea 

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-plugins, tinymce, jeditable

Hi I have a mix of tinyMCE jquery plugin and jeditable on a textarea. When the editable element is clicked it is turned into a tinymce iframe. Now I need to pass the iframe content back to the textarea using tinymce.triggerSave() BEFORE the form is ajaxed.

Anyone any idea?

```
    function editNote(){
    $('.edit').editable('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/notes/edit', {
         type      : 'textarea',
         onblur    : 'ignore',
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'OK',
         indicator : "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/images/indicator.gif'>",
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'

     });
 }

 $('.edit').live('click', function(){
    editNote();
    $('textarea').tinymce({
                    // Location of TinyMCE script
                    script_url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                    // General options
                    theme : "simple"
});
});
```

The code above calls the editNote function and then the tinymce js.

I'm looking for a way to run tinyMCE.triggerSave(); BEFORE the jeditable form is submitted. So something like the opposite of callback.

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this piece of code instead. You basically create a new type called mce.

```
$.fn.tinymce = function(options){
   return this.each(function(){
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, this.id);
   });
}

function initMCE(){
   tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textarea",
        theme : "advanced",
        ... // YOUR CUSTOMIZATION
      });
}

initMCE();

$.editable.addInputType('mce', {
   element : function(settings, original) {
      var textarea = $('<textarea id="'+$(original).attr("id")+'_mce"/>');
      if (settings.rows) {
         textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
      } else {
         textarea.height(settings.height);
      }
      if (settings.cols) {
         textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
      } else {
         textarea.width(settings.width);
      }
      $(this).append(textarea);
         return(textarea);
      },
   plugin : function(settings, original) {
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, $(original).attr("id")+'_mce');
      },
   submit : function(settings, original) {
      tinyMCE.triggerSave();
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, $(original).attr("id")+'_mce');
      },
   reset : function(settings, original) {
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, $(original).attr("id")+'_mce');
      original.reset(this);
   }
});
```

In your JEditable initiation make it of type mce. So:

```
    $(".edit").editable('ajax/save.php?editnotetext', {
        type : 'mce',
        ... // etc
    });
```

Comment: This looks good, I'll give it a try later and let you know. Cheers

Comment: My pleasure. I know how frustrating this is. Feel free to check my other posts for more TinyMCE+JEditable drama.

Comment: This is ancient, but I've just implemented it using tinyMCE version 4. It works if you replace `mceAddControl` with `mceAddEditor`, and `mceRemoveControl` with `mceRemoveEditor`

Comment: Also, the definition of `$.fn.tinymce` seems to be redundant - not sure what that was supposed to do. I haven't used it in my code.